# Excel VBA want to delete non blanks below Row 5

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to VBA I am trying to delete rows below my headers and titles from row 5, all rows that have data in them, before copying new data from a different sheet.

Any suggestions please, sorry if this a silly question

Comment: This wasn't a silly question at all. Btw, welcome to stackoverflow, if any of these answers fits you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Activesheet.UsedRange.Offset(5).Clear
```

...or

```
Activesheet.UsedRange.Offset(5).EntireRow.Clear
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("6:" & Rows.Count).Clear
```

Comment: Or .delete  Clear sometimes doesn't reset the scroll bars which I find super annoying but mostly harmless.

Comment: @user1229645: I see you unaccepted my answer. seems like you again got stuck with rows.count? to clear only row 6 change the above code to  Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(6).Clear ;) And to delete it use .Delete instead of .Clear :)

Comment: Siddharth Rout - Thanks very much for all your assistance unfortunately I cannot accept both answers. But they both work very well

Comment: I would use Sidd's solution to be safe, the used range does not always start at row 1.